# Android. Coroutine. Retrofit 2. Handler Error

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, coroutine

Подскажите, пожалуйста, хороший материал для изучения, который показывает как правильно обрабатывать исключения в retrofit 2 + coroutine.

```
scope.launch {
        try {
            val response : Response<AuthResponse>

            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                response = postAPI.setAuth(key, id, authRequest)
            }

            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                view.onSuccessful()
            } else {
                when (JsonToErrorMessage.getErrorMessage(response.errorBody()!!)) {
                    ErrorResponse.WRONG_CODE -> {
                        view.onWrongCode()
                    }
                    ErrorResponse.CODE_TIME_OUT -> {
                        view.onTimeout()
                    }
                    else -> {
                        view.onUnknownError()
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            view.onNetworkError()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            view.onUnknownError()
        }
    }
```

Каждый раз писать такое, подсказывает мне, что это неправильно, хотя достаточно много примеров, где так и делается. Да и к тому же каждый раз дублирование кода.

Comment: Если судить по примеру кода, вы можете вернуться к асинхронному вызову Retrofit. Написать один раз свою реализацию Callback<T>, передавать в него view и использовать везде. Сейчас это у вас выглядит как корутины ради корутин.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну корутины или не корутины, вас все равно придется что-то такое писать. В той же RX Java вы в методе `subscribe()` постоянно обрабатываете `onError()`. Но сделать это красивее можно.

Я покажу вам 1 пример.

- Сперва вам нужен класс `Result`, некая сущность которая отвечает за результат. В Котлине есть прекрасная штука `sealed class`, что-то вроде такого:

  ```
  sealed class Result<out T> {
      data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
      data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
  }
  ```

  В нем есть 2 состояния:

  - **Success** - когда данные пришли и все ок
  - **Error** - в случае ошибки
  - Так же вы можете добавить свои состояния. Можно к примеру разные типы ошибок возвращать в разных состояниях. Или к примеру добавить состояние `Loading`. Тут по своим потребностям.
- После чего можно создать базовый класс вроде такого:

  ```
  abstract class BaseRemoteProvider<RESPONSE>() : NetworkProvider<RESPONSE> {

      abstract suspend fun getResponse(): Response<RESPONSE>

      override suspend fun get(): Result<RESPONSE> {
          return try {
              val result = parseResponse(getResponse())
              Result.Success(result)
          } catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
              Result.Error(e)
          } catch (e: ConnectException) {
              Result.Error(e)
          } catch (e: Exception) {
              Result.Error(e)
          }
      }

      private fun parseResponse(response: Response<RESPONSE>): RESPONSE {
          val data: RESPONSE?

          if (response.isSuccessful)
              data = response.body()
          else
              throw getNetworkException(response)

          if (data != null)
              return data
          else
              throw NetworkException(statusMessage = "Generated Network Error Something went wrong")
      }

      private fun getNetworkException(response: Response<RESPONSE>): NetworkException {
          val type = object : TypeToken<NetworkException>() {}.type
          return Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody()!!.charStream(), type)
      }
  }
  ```

  Что здесь происходит? Мы отправляем запрос на сервер и проверяем его. Если с ответом все ок, то мы оборачиваем этот ответ в наш `Result.Success` и возвращаем его дальше. Если какая-то ошибка - мы оборачиваем в `Resuslt.Error`. NetworkExceprion это моя кастомная ошибка, которую отдает бек и метод `getNetworkException(response)` как раз мапит ответ в объект.

  Вот сам `NetworkExceprion` для наглядности:

  ```
  data class NetworkException(
      @SerializedName("status_code") val statusCode: Int = 0,
      @SerializedName("status_message") val statusMessage: String = "",
      @SerializedName("success") val isSuccessful: Boolean = false
  ) : Exception()
  ```
- Собственно это все. В вашей ViewModel или любом другом месте вы обрабатываете это так:

  ```
  fun loadData() {
        backgroundScope.launch {
            when (val result = remoteProvider.get()) {
                is Result.Success -> handleData(result.data.items)
                is Result.Error -> handleError(result.exception)
            }
        }
    }
  ```